# Boolean checkbox, set value of textfield

Tags: javascript, jsf, checkbox, primefaces

I'm trying to create a form where you can give a range through primefaces slider component, with an optinally exact or inexact upper limit (that is the upper limit of the range could be 1000 or >1000). The optionality of the range is indicated through a checkbox.

In a form I have the following components:

```
<p:outputLabel value="From 1:"  />
<p:inputText style="display: block;margin-bottom: 3px;" id="lower" value="#{dilution.lower}" />
<p:outputLabel value="To 1:" />
<p:inputText style="display: block;margin-bottom: 3px;" widgetVar="upp" id="upper" value="#{dilution.upper}" />
<p:outputLabel value="Greater than 1000" for="above1000" />
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="above1000" value="#{dilution.bigger}" valueChangeListener="#{dilution.above}"  >
    <p:ajax update="upper" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:outputText style="display: block;" id="displayRange" value="Choose from intervall 1:1 till 1:1000"/>                        
<p:slider id="dfact" displayTemplate="For intervall 1:{min} till 1:{max}" for="lower,upper" range="true" step="1" minValue="1" maxValue="1000" />
```

When the checkbox is checked I would like the value in the upper limit textfield to change to 1000 and if it is unchecked I don't want it to alter the value of the textfield.

I have almost got this to work using a valueChangeListner attached to the checkbox.

In the backing bean `dilution` I have the following valueChangeListner:

```
public void above(ValueChangeEvent event){
    if((Boolean)event.getNewValue()){
        upper = 1000;
    }        
}
```

which sets the value of the textfield `upper` to 1000. My problem is that it does this if I change the value of the textfield to some other number, then uncheck the textbox.

I'm guessing this is because the `upper` backing bean value is still set to 1000 from the previous time. I tried making the ajax call process the `upper` component like this:

```
<p:ajax update="upper" process="upper" />
```

because I thought this would make it process the `upper` component (and therefore change the backing bean value based on what was written in the textfield) before the update. But when I do this the textfield doesn't get set at all.

I then felt maybe using javascript to do this made more sense, avoiding any unneccassary calls to the server but can't figure out how to do it. I considered using `widgetVar` somehow but I can't find any documentation showing me how to use it.

Also it would be good if changing the value in the textfield changed where the slider was set, but this is less important.

Any hints what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The way you're trying to do is not right.

I've re-written the example for you

***XHTML Code***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

<h:head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

</script>
    <link rel=" stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"></link>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:panel header="Form">

                <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                    <h:outputText value="From:" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{testBean.lower}" id="lower"></p:inputText>

                    <h:outputText value="To:" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{testBean.upper}" id="upper"></p:inputText>

                    <h:outputText value="Change Upper to Max" />
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{testBean.maxUpper}">
                        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{testBean.chageMax}"
                            update=":form:upper"></p:ajax>
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

                    <h:outputText style="display: block;" id="displayRange"
                        value="Choose from intervall 1:1 till 1:1000" />
                    <p:slider id="dfact"
                        displayTemplate="For intervall 1:{min} till 1:{max}"
                        for=":form:lower,:form:upper" range="true" step="1" minValue="1"
                        maxValue="1000" />
                </h:panelGrid>

            </p:panel>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>

</h:head>

</html>
```

***Managed Bean (back bean)***

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean {

    private int lower;
    private int upper;
    private boolean maxUpper;

    public void chageMax() {
        if (maxUpper) {
            upper = 1000;
        } else {
            upper = 0;
        }
    }

    public boolean isMaxUpper() {
        return maxUpper;
    }

    public void setMaxUpper(boolean maxUpper) {
        this.maxUpper = maxUpper;
    }

    public int getLower() {
        return lower;
    }

    public void setLower(int lower) {
        this.lower = lower;
    }

    public int getUpper() {
        return upper;
    }

    public void setUpper(int upper) {
        this.upper = upper;
    }
}
```

***Generated OUTPUT***

[image: Initial page load]

[image: When tick box selected]

[image: Using Slider]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answaer. But won't this set the upper limit to 0 if you uncheck the checkbox? I don't wan't to overwrite possible userinput written in the textfield before unchecking the box.

Comment: You want to reset the upper limit to input text on untick??